# Kibana visualise count of not null of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I am using elastic search kibana for data visualisation.Suppose i have following json in elasticsearch

{
"name":"Aravind",
"dob":"12-2-17"
}
{
"name":"Aakask",
"dob":""
}
{
"name":"Rinu",
"dob":"14-2-17"
}
{
"name":"Alex",
"dob":"7-1-17"
}

I need to visualise total count of not null dob field.
In this example total dob = 3.Because one value for dob is empty(""), so no need to count that.
Any one tell me how to implement this with kibana?

Answer (score -2):

Please look at [null value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) documentation, there you will see that you can define in the mapping value that elastic could not be find, and then kibana don't be count it.